# MySQL: Select all twos of a kind with highest ids

Tags: mysql, sql, max, greatest-n-per-group

I have table that consists multiple rows of a kind that have different ids. (Kinds are many. Ids are unique. Both columns are indexed.) 
Now I need to select the two with highest ids of each kind.
Here is what I do.

```
select max(c.id), max(d.id) from theTable c left join
theTable d on c.id > d.id and c.kind=d.kind
where c.id > constant group by c.kind;
```

However the query above doesnt perform very well and it is not a big surprise.
Ive figured out a faster version of it...

```
select c.id, max(d.id) from (select max(id) id, kind from theTable    
where id > constatnt group by kind) c left join
theTable d on c.id > d.id and c.kind=d.kind group by c.kind;
```

.... but still it is not fast enough

Is there a more efficient way to achieve the same result?
Thanks!


**Edit:**
theTbale is a history table so my task is to get the current values and the previous ones for each kind and compare them as part of an expression (logical operations, coalesces, ifs and etc) and determine if expression results are different

here is an example resultset:

```
+-----------+-----------+
| max(c.id) | max(d.id) |
+-----------+-----------+
|      1747 |      NULL |
|      1701 |      1432 |
|      1703 |      1434 |
|      1706 |      1437 |
|      1707 |      1438 |
|      1751 |      NULL |
|      1713 |      1444 |
|      1750 |      NULL |
|      1709 |      1440 |
|      1742 |      1741 |
|      1711 |      1442 |
|      1746 |      1745 |
|      1708 |      1439 |
|      1719 |      1450 |
|      1725 |      1456 |
|      1723 |      1454 |
|      1740 |      1733 |
|      1705 |      1436 |
|      1702 |      1433 |
|      1749 |      1748 |
|      1712 |      1443 |
|      1718 |      1449 |
|      1722 |      1453 |
|      1728 |      1459 |
|      1721 |      1452 |
|      1739 |      1731 |
|      1714 |      1445 |
|      1717 |      1448 |
|      1716 |      1447 |
|      1724 |      1455 |
|      1710 |      1441 |
|      1727 |      1458 |
|      1720 |      1451 |
|      1738 |      NULL |
|      1715 |      1446 |
|      1704 |      1435 |
|      1726 |      1457 |
|      1758 |      1757 |
+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: I see no reason for an outer join.

Comment: Could you please post sample data and the expected result? Your task is not very clear.  Performance (especially for large data sets) often depends on table indexing.  What indexes do you have?

Comment: The outer join is required because not every kind has two *id* values exceeding the constant. Unless you intend to exclude kinds without a "second largest" *id*, you need an outer join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following may perform pretty well:

```
select kind, max(id) as maxid,
       (select id from t t2 where t2.kind = t.kind and t2.id < max(t1.id) order by id desc limit 1) as secondId
from t
group by kind
```

This will work well *if* you have an index on `kind, id`.

Comment: Don't forget to filter on `id > constant`. The inner query can be reformulated as `select max(id) t t2 where t2.kind = t1.kind and t2.id < max(t1.id)` rather than `select id ... order by id desc limit 1`, but I'm not sure if that has any performance implications.

Comment: Gordon thank you for your answer. Ive tested it and it betters my first query by little but it is 40% slower than my second query. However Ill vote your answer up because it is a nice solution.

Comment: @dudelgrincen . . . Do you have an index on `(kind, id)`?  Not a separate index on each one, but one index on both (in that order).

Comment: I do not have...Ill try to create one and test.

Comment: Compound index improved performance a bit but I am happy with seperate index performance since difference is very small. It seemed that my actual query didnt use index (oh god!) so Ive just forced it to use the index. Performance is almost 200 times better. And it still seems that my second query does the job fastest.

Comment: Thank you for giving me a hint. I am accepting your answer. Index was the problem not query.

Answer (score 2):

What if instead of producing *(kind, id, id)* tuples with one row for each kind, your result set was *(kind, id)* with two rows per kind? I'm not sure if this will be more performant without running it myself, though.

```
SELECT x.kind, x.id
FROM (SELECT a.kind, a.id
        FROM theTable a
        LEFT OUTER JOIN theTable b
          ON a.kind = b.kind
         AND a.id < b.id
       GROUP BY a.id
       HAVING COUNT(*) < 2
       ORDER BY b.id) x
WHERE x.id > constant
ORDER BY x.kind;
```

The last `ORDER BY` clause is just to make it easier for you to verify results, so omit it when evaluating performance. Note that some *kinds* may only have one *id* exceeding your constant, so you'll only have one *(kind, id)* row for that kind.

Comment: Ive tried it despite it is not exactly what I wanted. I could use it but it is as fast as my first try. Thanks anyway! :) Ill vote your answer up because of your time